# Keep only data.frame rows where ID is different to ID of following row

Tags: r

I have a data.frame. I want to extract the users data where `id[i] != id[i+1]`. In other words, the new data.frame should remove any row where the ID in the original data.frame is the same as the ID if the following row.

What I am doing is as follows:

```
counter <- 0 
temp_bind_1 <-
  read.csv("/Users/dushyanttanna/Documents/R_codes/temp_bind.csv")
##an empty file... just with header##

for (i in 2:100000) {
  if (df_merged$Id[i] != df_merged$Id[i+1]) {
    temp_file <- data.frame(temp_bind + df1[i,])
    counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
print(counter) # just to see how many rows are there.... 
write.csv(temp_file,"temp_bind_final.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

But it fails to give desired output.

Comment: df_merged is my file..It is a merging of two different .csv files.

Comment: Sorry my id is not numeric. One example of id is 5657ebdfe924d0ab47ff7aa7. I will try to run this code now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example demonstrating how to do this.

Let's make some dummy data to work with

```
set.seed(123)
x = data.frame(Id = sample(letters[1:3],10,T), value = rnorm(10))
#    Id      value
# 1   a  1.7150650
# 2   c  0.4609162
# 3   b -1.2650612
# 4   c -0.6868529
# 5   c -0.4456620
# 6   a  1.2240818
# 7   b  0.3598138
# 8   c  0.4007715
# 9   b  0.1106827
# 10  b -0.5558411
```

Now to extract the rows where id[i] != id[i+1], we can do

```
x[c(diff(as.integer(x$Id)) !=0, TRUE), ]
#    Id      value
# 1   a  1.7150650
# 2   c  0.4609162
# 3   b -1.2650612
# 5   c -0.4456620
# 6   a  1.2240818
# 7   b  0.3598138
# 8   c  0.4007715
# 10  b -0.5558411
```

Note that you do not specify how you want to handle the final row of the data.frame (which does not have a following row we can compare it to).  The above code assumes you want to keep the final row.  If, instead, you need to remove it, you can use

```
x[c(diff(as.integer(x$Id)) !=0, FALSE), ]
```

Note, also, that this approach assumes that the Id column is a factor or an integer.  If it is not, then you should do `x$Id = factor(x$Id)` first.

Comment: @dushyanttanna glad it helped.  Do you mind if I edit your question to make it more clear.  It is quite unclear the way it is now (which is no doubt why it got down votes and close votes)

Comment: By all means @dww. I am very new this tackoverflow. So not great at asking questions but happy to learn.